# Insert Media link not working

Tags: links, fieldtype

I have an item that has two language versions - *en* & *jp*

For a `General Link` field in this item, I have used `insert media link` for both en & jp, & pointed to a pdf file in the media library.

It works fine when the page loads in en, but for jp the link url comes as empty string.

When I check in code

```
LinkField linkField = item.Fields[fieldId.ToString()];
```

`linkFiled.LinkType` is "media" for en, but for jp it comes as "external"

Why is this happening and how to fix this.

**UPDATE:**

The raw value for the en version of the link field is

```
<link linktype="media" target="" id="{0B17D555-9CE5-48AC-803D-B81C7931F9A4}" />
```

and for jp it is

```
<link text="Savings Bonds BE 2560 No1" linktype="media" target="" id="{0B17D555-9CE5-48AC-803D-B81C7931F9A4}" />
```

using sc8.2u4

Comment: Can you check the raw value of the field in en & jp?

Comment: @Gatogordo It is a pdf file and for the "Media" field the raw value says "[Blob Value]" for both versions

Comment: It's the raw value of the link field that you could check - that should not be "blob"

Comment: @Gatogordo I have updated my question. Could you please have a look.

Comment: I guess you have published the jp version of the pdf, right?

Comment: Is it versioned or unversioned media?

Comment: @MarkCassidy versioned

Comment: I'd check if the field is shared or not, I guess it's not and this is way you can see different raw value for different languages

Comment: If it's versioned media, you need an "en" and "jp" version of your media item.